# Representation of Hilbert functionals in terms of dual basis

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $\mathscr{H}$ be a complex separable Hilbert space with (orthonormal) Hilbert basis $\{e_{n}\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$. By Riesz Representation Theorem, if $f: \mathscr{H}\to \mathbb{C}$ is a given functional, there exists $y \in \mathscr{H}$ such that:
$$f(x) = \langle y,x\rangle$$
for every $x \in \mathscr{H}$, where $||f|| = ||y||$. Thus, if $\mathscr{H}^{*}$ is the dual space of $\mathscr{H}$, we established a conjugate linear map $T:\mathscr{H}\to \mathscr{H}^{*}$ such that $\mathscr{H}\ni y \mapsto Ty := f$, so that $\mathscr{H}^{*}\cong \mathscr{H}$. Now, $(\forall n \in \mathbb{N})$ let $\epsilon_{n}$ be defined by $\epsilon_{n} := Te_{n}$.

**Question:** How can I prove that $\{\epsilon_{n}\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is an orthonormal basis on $\mathscr{H}^{*}$ so that every $f \in \mathscr{H}^{*}$ can be written as:
$$f = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} f_{n}\epsilon_{n}$$
where $(\forall n\in \mathbb{N})$ $f_{n} \in \mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Should the map $T$ be conjugate linear? Notice that the scalar field is $\mathbb{C}$ and hence the inner product on $\mathscr{H}$ is sesquilinear only (instead of bilinear if the scalar field is $\mathbb{R}$).

Comment: By conjugate linear, we mean $T(\alpha x+y) = \bar{\alpha}Tx + Ty$, where $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$ and $x,y\in\mathscr{H}$.

Comment: @DannyPak-KeungChan, yes, you are correct! I'm gonna add this to my post! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to talk about orthonormal bases in $H^*$ one first needs that space to have an inner product. This is not specified in the question, but assuming it is the natural one defined by $$\langle \phi,\psi\rangle_{H^*}:=\langle T^{-1}\psi,T^{-1}\phi\rangle_H$$ then it follows that $\epsilon_n$ are orthonormal: $$\langle\epsilon_n,\epsilon_m\rangle_{H^*}=\langle e_m,e_n\rangle_H=\delta_{nm}.$$

Suppose $f\in\mathrm{Span}(\epsilon_n)^\perp$, that is $\langle \epsilon_n,f\rangle_{H^*}=0$ for all $n$. Then, taking $x=T^{-1}f$, $$\forall n\in\mathbb{N},\quad\langle x,e_n\rangle_H=0,\qquad\therefore x=0,\quad \therefore f=0$$ This implies that $\epsilon_n$ is an orthonormal basis for $H^*$. Moreover, for any functional, $f=\sum_n\langle\epsilon_n,f\rangle_{H^*}\epsilon_n$, by the standard theory of Hilbert spaces.